# Is there a way to add profile pics in e-mails sent from code

Tags: php, email, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

So, what I am doing is I am using Sendgdrid's API ([PHP API Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)) to send e-mails. The sending part works, I just want to overhaul it a little to add some more customization, but I am not sure if it's possible. I am using CodeIgniter so I am skipping some code, but you get the general idea.

What I want to achieve is to customize this part

[image: Example of what I want to modify]

I want the company logo to appear there instead of the automatically generated A.

I want to achieve this:

[image]

Is there some header I need to modify?

My mail sending process is this (fictional data):

```php
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("noreply@mail.com", "Sender Name");
$email->setSubject("Mail Subject");
$email->addTo($mail_data->email, $mail_data->name);
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", $this->load->view('mails/recovery', $mail_data, TRUE)
);

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($this->config->item('sendgrid_api_key'));

try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    // do some stuff
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // do some other stuff
}
```

So the mail arrives correct and everything, but is there a way to add like an avatar for the mail sender? Like the company's logo or something. Is there a way to do this via code?

I checked something about creating a google account, but what if I am using a noreply@ address and also what happens if for another mail I use a different address? I'd have to add google accounts to each one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091844/send-email-with-profile-picture-php-mail-function

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi I checked that but I am not sure that's the only way to do this, moreover when a noreply@ address is used. Isn't there a way to customize this?

Comment: The image is associated with the account. It isn't sent in the email.

Comment: So, what happens if the account doesn't exist? Or do I need to create an account and disable its inbox?

Comment: Just as an additional question. What happens if there's already G-Suite enabled for that domain, is there a way to do this without creating another e-mail? It would cost $6 USD a month just to do that.

Comment: Sending an email with a From header doesn't cost anything. If the From header matches I presume Google associates it to image record they have. They likely have some authentication they use though. That could easily be tested though.

Comment: So I should check for a specific account that has the logo and use it as a From header? @user3783243

Comment: Hi @MihailMinkov, is https://sendgrid.com/blog/what-is-bimi/ what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatthewSetter ooh, this is new! The question is a little outdated now, but how much support is there for BIMI?

Comment: Not sure, but I'll find out and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on Matthew Setter's comment on my question, I researched a little bit and the solution to this is the BIMI DNS record. BIMI stands for [Brand Indicators for Message Identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_Indicators_for_Message_Identification)

It requires the following:

1. You need an SVG version of your icon/logo/pic and the max weight of the image must be 32kb. The image must be publicly accessible, so it must be something like `https://www.yourdomain.com/images/icon.svg`
2. You need a BIMI Certificate, that's the tricky part, because they are currently extremely expensive, Digicert sells them as Verified Mark Certificate and they cost $1,499.00 USD per year, so it won't do for most people. You also need to host the certificate also on your domain on a public link, something like `https://www.yourdomain.com/cert/bimi.pem`
3. You need to have a defined DMARC policy, if you don't have one it might show warnings/errors.
4. You need to add a TXT record with the following structure

   1. The name of the record is: `default._bimi`
   2. v (version) BIMI1: `v=BIMI1;`
   3. l (location) of the SVG image: `https://www.yourdomain.com/images/icon.svg`
   4. a (address I think) of your certificate: `https://www.yourdomain.com/cert/bimi.pem`

So the end result is something like this:

```
TXT default._bimi "v=BIMI1;l=https://www.yourdomain.com/images/icon.svg;a=https://www.yourdomain.com/cert/bimi.pem" 3600
```

I hope the certificate authorities reduce the price of this as it can be useful for many businesses but $1,499.00 for a certificate is way too much for the regular business owner.

**OTHER RESOURCES**

You can also use [these tools](https://easydmarc.com/tools/bimi-record-generator) to generate/validate BIMI records.

Comment: Found a slightly cheaper option at Entrust for $1,299 a year. You also need to have a registered trademark for your logo (from an official intellectual property office)