# How to include the profile photo in an email sent with mailkit?

Tags: c#, .net, email

As the title suggests, I would like to understand if it is possible, using C#, to be able to choose the profile image of an email sent via mailkit.

[image: How to set this image with C#?]

I am not referring to including images in the body of the email.

I have used this code in a C# console application and it works.

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Text;

namespace MailKitTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create email message
            var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("Ok Novità <test@test.it>"));
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("test@test.it"));
            email.Subject = "Test Email Subject";
            email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = "<h1>Example HTML Message Body</h1>" };

            // send email
            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect("[custom_smtp]", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            smtp.Authenticate("[custom_username]", "[custom_password]");
            smtp.Send(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
}
```

If with mailkit it is not possible to set the thumbnail next to the profile, is there any other way?

Comment: Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091844/send-email-with-profile-picture-php-mail-function) it seems that there is no programmatic way to do this. For Google it seems the best way is to create an account with the sender email, but that might only work if the recipient has that account as a contact.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response. I'd be looking for something more general and not just limited to Gmail accounts. Perhaps using Gravatar could be the answer to this problem.